# Parse request JSON in Spring REST controller called from jQuery ajax

Tags: java, jquery, json, rest, spring-boot

I'm building a HTML form which upon submit, calls a REST api and sends the form values in JSON.

Like this:

**Rest call:**

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/backend";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: requestJson,
    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log( errorThrown );
    }
});
```

**Example JSON:**

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "domain": "planes",
  "types": [
    "military",
    "commercial"
  ],
  "details": [
    {
      "military": {
        "name": "f18",
        "country": "US"
      }
    },
    {
      "commercial": {
        "name": "a380",
        "country": "Finland"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

On backend, I'm running a spring-boot application which accepts this JSON as request and performs some operations.

```
class MyRequestDTO {
    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty("domain")
    private String domain;

    @JsonProperty("types")
    private String[] types;

    ......
}
```

**REST call in Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public Map<String, List<String>> createSot(@Valid MyRequestDTO myRequestDTO) {

    System.out.println(sotDTO.getId());         //THIS WORKS
    System.out.println(sotDTO.getDomain());     //THIS WORKS
    String[] types = sotDTO.getTypes();         //THIS DOES NOT WORK
    for(String e: types) {
        System.out.println("type: " + e);
    }

}
```

Issue is I'm not able to get types array & it is throwing null exception.

Any suggestions what I need to change.

*Thanks*

Comment: Did you try with List<String>?

Comment: That should be a list, a collection. Try what Lawrence suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Change `private String[] types;` to `private List<String> types;` would help.

Plus, as you mentioned you're using spring-boot as backend service, so you don't really need `@JsonProperty` annotation at all. Remove them to make less code.